# How to rename a hive table without changing location?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Based on the Hive doc below:

> Rename Table
>
> ALTER TABLE table_name RENAME TO new_table_name;
>
> This statement lets you change the name of a table to a different name.
>
> As of version 0.6, a rename on a managed table moves its HDFS location as well. (Older Hive versions just renamed the table in the metastore without moving the HDFS location.)

Is there any way to rename a table without changing the location?

Comment: Have you tried using external tables instead of hive managed tables: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ExternalTables

Comment: Even with a "managed" table, you should be able to set a non-default *location* => RENAME, then change *location* back to the original default, then move all HDFS files back... At this point you should ask yourself: why do I need to force the location? Does it make sense?? You give no reason for that, so I assume it's a bad idea.

Answer (score 36):

Yeah we can do that. You just need to follow below three commands in sequence.

1. Lets say you have a external table test_1 in hive. And you want to rename it test_2 which should point test_2 location not test_1. Then you need to convert this table into Managed table using below command.
   test_1 -> pointing to test_1 location

   ```
   ALTER TABLE db_name.test_1 SET TBLPROPERTIES('EXTERNAL'='FALSE');
   ```
2. Rename the table name.

   ```
   ALTER TABLE db_name.test_1 RENAME TO db_name.test_2;
   ```
3. Again convert the managed table after renaming to external table.

   ```
   ALTER TABLE db_name.test_2 SET TBLPROPERTIES('EXTERNAL'='TRUE');
   ```

db_name.test_2 table will point the test_2 location. If we do it without making the managed table it will point the test_1 location.

Answer (score 7):

ALTER TABLE does not follow the databasename.tablename syntax in Hive like it does in CREATE or SELECT.
Mention the databasename first and then run alter table statement.

syntax as below

```
USE databasename;
ALTER TABLE old_tablename RENAME TO new_tablename;
```

Answer (score 5):

As of Hive 2.2.0 a managed table's HDFS location is moved only if the table is created without a LOCATION clause and under its database directory.[Link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-RenameTable)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the command executed

```
ALTER TABLE old_ratings RENAME TO ratings;
```